# Rails 3 Jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate, jquery

I have this js code

```
$(".new_milestone").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).submitWithAjax();
   },
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
     }
   });
```

It all works, errorPlacement and the submitWithAjax function. But when I post the form the second time without reloading the page, the form gets posted two times. Next time 3 times and so on.

When I do this

```
 $(".new_milestone").validate({
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertBefore(element);
             }
           });
$(".new_milestone").submitWithAjax();
```

It works, but it does the ajax post even if the form is not valid.

The submitWithAjax function looks like this (thanks Ryan Bates)

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() { 

    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    $('.spinning').show(); 
    $("#dialog_form").dialog("close")
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};
```

Any ideas on stopping this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `ssubmitWithAjax` function doesn't * actually* submit (fire the event), it *attaches a submit handler* for when the `submit` happens (which the normal behavior is doing)...since you're calling it in a submit situation, just remove the handler wrapper and actually submit, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  $.post(this.attr("action"), this.serialize(), null, "script");
  $('.spinning').show(); 
  $("#dialog_form").dialog("close")
  return false;
};
```

Note the `.attr("action")` change, because `this` is not a jQuery object, not a `<form>` DOM element since it's directly in the plugin.

---

Previously, you were attaching an *additional* `submit` handler each time, which is why you get 1, 2, 3.... submits, by just calling the submit code you want, this won't happen, since inside `submitHandler` is the valid place to go ahead and submit anyway.

As an aside, the callback function to [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is optional, so you can leave off that `null,` and it'll function properly.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any experience with rails. Removing the submit handler messed up the POST route for rails. Is there any way to use the validate function and not be "in a submit situation"

Comment: @Andreas - The `submitHandler` function only gets called as part of the `submit` event on the `<form>` if the validation checks out.  Are you using my code above with the *first* `.validate()` version in your answer?

Comment: Yes, I am using the first one. I was thinking I could try without the submitHandler function. Perhaps some if statement on a valid() function?

Comment: @Andreas - I'm unclear what you mean by "messed up the POST route"...what's the current behavior?

Comment: When you post a form in rails you have to go to a spesific route (or URL). In this case it sends a POST request to localhost:3000/milestones. When I remove the submit call in the submitWithAjax function, it sends a POST request to localhost:3000/firms/1/projects/3. This is the page I am on when I post. Rails looks at the class of the form to send the POST to the correct URL. It seems like it looses it when I remove the submit call:

Comment: Ah ok, I see the problem here, `this` in a plugin revers to the jQuery object (which doesn't have a `.action` property) not the form itself, let me fix the above, it should be `this.attr("action")` then you'll be all set.

Comment: One million Thanks Nick! It's working now. You just saved me from going bold ;).